# its always showing port closed even when have a listener setup and its going the listener

Tags: python-3.x, port-scanning

So I used the socket connect_ex which means in the if statement if the result will be true the port is closed because it's true when it gets an error but if it's false the port is open but it's not working.
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import socket 

ip = raw_input("Enter the IP address:   ")

port =input("Enter The Port Number:  ")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

if sock.connect_ex((ip,port)):

   print"Port" , port, "is closed"  

else:

   print "Port", port, "is closed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are twice saying the port would be closed, in the `else`-statement as well, so you will never get a positive response from your program.

Comment: Yah Thanks for that it was really helpfull